# Uber API -Loading of promo codes against an Uber user

Tags: uber-api

I have been reading through the documentation of the Uber API and cannot find information on loading a promotion code against a specific Uber user.

Is there any way I can load a promo code / voucher against a specific user so that user does not have to type the promo code in? In short I would like to credit a Uber user account.

I have contacted Uber but have had no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the API through patch /ME endpoint. Please see documentation for this here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/me-patch

It sounds like you potentially might also be interested in deeplinks that can do that. "The applyPromo action allows you to launch the Uber app directly to the apply promotion screen and pre-fill a promotion code. The action takes a single parameter, the promo code you want to pre-fill for the user." See more about using deeplinks here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-promotions/introduction

Also, until this SO post, I have not seen this question come in from you on any of the Uber API support channels, listed here: https://developer.uber.com/support

Hope that helps!

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you!